# ArgumentError in Posts#edit - first argument nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am going through the "Getting Started with Rails Tutorial" and am stuck on update aka Edit.  It is throwing the `ArgumentError` in Posts#edit - first argument in form can't be nil or empty.  Here is the highlighted line:

First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Extracted source (around line #1):

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
```

It seems to have started when I implemented the partial forms part of the tutorial.

Here is the post_contoller, edit action and _forms.html respectively:

**Post_controller:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def new
@post = Post.new
end
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy

  redirect_to posts_path
end
private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

**Edit.html**

```
<h1>Edit post</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

**_form.html**

```
 <%= form_for @post do |f| %>  
 <% if @post.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
     <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
       this post from being saved:</h2>
     <ul>
     <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
       <li><%= msg %></li>
     <% end %>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <% end %>
   <p>
     <%= f.label :title %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :title %>
   </p>

   <p>
     <%= f.label :text %><br>
     <%= f.text_area :text %>
   </p>

   <p>
     <%= f.submit %>
   </p>
 <% end %>
```

The error shows an ID of "7" which is the record I am trying to update.

All other functions work (show, new, delete) and BTW "new" uses the same partial form and works fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You don't have `edit` action defined in `PostsController`.

Comment: Great catch, that was it.  Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

U should add this in your _controller.rb

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass in the post object as local. You cannot directly access instance variables defined in controller in partial. It will be nil

```
<h1>Edit post</h1>
<%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:post => @post} %>
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

In the partial

```
<%= form_for post do |f| %>
```

Comment: Hmmm. I made the changes you suggested and got the same results.  It's interesting that the "New" action works using the same partial.  Here is New.html:   
   `<h1>New post</h1>`
   `<%= render 'form' %> `
   `<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>`

Answer (score 0):

**check below the private is used for the below function only and write all functions above this:**
`private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end`